# 3D OSM buildings seems to be floating and shifted after adding terrain effect in Cesium

Tags: javascript, terrain, cesium, 3d-model

I had made a 3D view of the osm buildings using cesium. In which i had added a terrain effect using the standard cesium terrain provider as below

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');
var terrainProvider = new Cesium.CesiumTerrainProvider({
  url : '//assets.agi.com/stk-terrain/world'
});
viewer.terrainProvider = terrainProvider;
var dataSource2 = new Cesium.GeoJsonDataSource();
var promise = dataSource2.load('../../SampleData/Hubli_Buildings.geojson');
promise.then(function(dataSource2) {
    viewer.dataSources.add(dataSource2);
    viewer.zoomTo(dataSource2);


    //Get the array of entities
    var entities2 = dataSource2.entities.values;

    var colorHash = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < entities2.length; i++) {
        //For each entity, create a random color based on the state name.
        //Some states have multiple entities, so we store the color in a
        //hash so that we use the same color for the entire state.
        var entity = entities2[i];
        var name = entity.Elev_in_m;
        var color = colorHash[name];
        if (!color) {
            color = Cesium.Color.BROWN; 
            colorHash[name] = color;
        }

        //Set the polygon material to our random color.
        entity.polygon.material = color;
        //Remove the outlines.
        entity.polygon.outline = false;

        //Extrude the polygon based on the state's population.  Each entity
        //stores the properties for the GeoJSON feature it was created from
        //Since the population is a huge number, we divide by 50.
        entity.polygon.extrudedHeight = entity.properties.Elev_in_m;
        entity.polygon.height = entity.properties.Elev_in_m;
    }
}).otherwise(function(error){
    //Display any errrors encountered while loading.
    window.alert(error);
});
```

After adding the terrain, my geojson 3D seems to be floated and shifted as below

[image]

I would like to know how to avoid this shifting effect after adding the terrain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polygons don't automatically pick up terrain height values when you enable Cesium terrain.  You need to set `entity.polygon.height` for each polygon, and also add that same height to your existing `entity.polygon.extrudedHeight`.  In other words, `extrudedHeight` is the absolute height (above WGS84) of the top of the extrusion, so if you have a building of fixed height, you must raise both `height` and `extrudedHeight` in unison to lift the building up onto the new terrain.

The [Cesium Terrain Demo](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=Terrain.html&label=All) includes a code sample showing how to read the height values at multiple points on terrain.  Click the `Sample Everest Terrain` button to see this in action.

*EDIT:* I copied the sampleTerrain code into the question's code above, and the buildings now sit on the terrain.  Here's the completed example:

```
// Selecting the terrain this way allows the base layer picker to show the selection.
var terrain = Cesium.createDefaultTerrainProviderViewModels();

var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
    terrainProviderViewModels: terrain,
    selectedTerrainProviderViewModel: terrain[1]
});

// This array will hold our cartographic height queries, one per building, and will
// also be populated with the answers.
var terrainSamplePositions = [];

var dataSource2 = new Cesium.GeoJsonDataSource();
var promise = dataSource2.load('../../SampleData/Hubli_Buildings.geojson');
promise.then(function(dataSource2) {
    viewer.dataSources.add(dataSource2);
    viewer.zoomTo(dataSource2);


    //Get the array of entities
    var entities2 = dataSource2.entities.values;

    var colorHash = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < entities2.length; i++) {
        //For each entity, create a random color based on the state name.
        //Some states have multiple entities, so we store the color in a
        //hash so that we use the same color for the entire state.
        var entity = entities2[i];
        var name = entity.Elev_in_m;
        var color = colorHash[name];
        if (!color) {
            color = Cesium.Color.BROWN; 
            colorHash[name] = color;
        }

        //Set the polygon material to our random color.
        entity.polygon.material = color;
        //Remove the outlines.
        entity.polygon.outline = false;

        // TODO: More sanity checking for undefined values etc.
        var position = entity.polygon.hierarchy.getValue().positions[0];
        terrainSamplePositions.push(Cesium.Cartographic.fromCartesian(position));

        //Extrude the polygon based on the state's population.  Each entity
        //stores the properties for the GeoJSON feature it was created from
        //Since the population is a huge number, we divide by 50.
        entity.polygon.extrudedHeight = entity.properties.Elev_in_m;
        entity.polygon.height = 0;
    }

    // Asking for terrain heights is asynchronous, because the answer may
    // reside on the terrain server.
    Cesium.when(Cesium.sampleTerrain(viewer.terrainProvider, 11, terrainSamplePositions), function() {
        // Update all building heights to sit on top of the terrain.
        for (var i = 0; i < entities2.length; i++) {
            var entity = entities2[i];
            var terrainHeight = terrainSamplePositions[i].height;
            // The bottom of the building sits on the terrain.
            entity.polygon.height = terrainHeight;
            // The top of the building adds the building height to the terrain height.
            entity.polygon.extrudedHeight = entity.properties.Elev_in_m + terrainHeight;
        }
    });

}).otherwise(function(error){
    //Display any errrors encountered while loading.
    console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had edited my post such that i had tried adding the code as per your suggestion.  But still the shift was there.And also my data has two layers one is road and the other is buildings. Only the Building layer has height informations. Please tell me where i am wrong.

Comment: Are you able to post a link to `Hubli_Buildings.geojson` ?

Comment: http://pastebin.ca/3489873

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: I updated my answer.  In the new code I sample the terrain once per polygon, and adjust the building extrusion accordingly.

Comment: Say i have two layers one is line and polygon. Polygon can be fit into terrain with your code above. How about my line can be done? It wont have any height properties. It also need to be fit into terrain without floating. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post a new question, with sample code that produces the line?  Thanks

Comment: Here is the link http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194334/line-layer-seems-to-be-floating-and-shifted-after-adding-terrain-effect-in-cesiu