# Line Layer seems to be floating and shifted after adding terrain effect in Cesium

Tags: javascript, terrain, cesium, 3d-model

I had made add a line layer using cesium. In which i had added a terrain effect using the standard cesium terrain provider as below

```
var dataSource1 = new Cesium.GeoJsonDataSource();
var roads = dataSource1.load('../../SampleData/roads.geojson');
roads.then(function(dataSource1) {
    viewer.dataSources.add(dataSource1);
    viewer.zoomTo(dataSource1);


    //Get the array of entities
    var entities1 = dataSource1.entities.values;

    var colorHash = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < entities1.length; i++) {
        //For each entity, create a random color based on the state name.
        //Some states have multiple entities, so we store the color in a
        //hash so that we use the same color for the entire state.
        var entity = entities1[i];
        var name = entity.name;
        var color = colorHash[name];
        if (!color) {
            color = Cesium.Color.BLACK; 
            colorHash[name] = color;
        }
        //Set the polygon material to our random color.
        entity.polyline.material = color;
        //Remove the outlines.
        entity.polyline.outline = false;

    }
}).otherwise(function(error){
    //Display any errrors encountered while loading.
    window.alert(error);
});
```

After adding the terrain, my geojson line layer seems to be floated and shifted as below
[image]

I would like to know how to avoid this floating effect of line layer alone after adding the terrain.

Comment: Can you post a sample of roads.geojson?

Comment: Yes here it is http://pastebin.com/cCTRe6wP

Comment: @emackey Any updates on this?Please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated the code to query for terrain heights and place the roads on terrain.  There's a little fudge factor, the roads are placed 1 meter above the terrain to try to keep them from intersecting the terrain.  This was needed because the roads are not sampled at the same frequency as the terrain samples.

```
var terrain = Cesium.createDefaultTerrainProviderViewModels();

var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
    terrainProviderViewModels: terrain,
    selectedTerrainProviderViewModel: terrain[1]
});

// This array will hold our cartographic height queries, and will
// also be populated with the answers.
var terrainSamplePositions = [];

var dataSource1 = new Cesium.GeoJsonDataSource();
var roads = dataSource1.load('../../SampleData/Hubli_Roads.geojson');
roads.then(function(dataSource1) {
    viewer.dataSources.add(dataSource1);
    viewer.zoomTo(dataSource1);

    //Get the array of entities
    var entities1 = dataSource1.entities.values;

    var colorHash = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < entities1.length; i++) {
        var entity = entities1[i];
        var name = entity.name;
        var color = colorHash[name];
        if (!color) {
            color = Cesium.Color.BLACK; 
            colorHash[name] = color;
        }
        entity.polyline.material = color;
        //Remove the outlines.
        entity.polyline.outline = false;

        var positions = entity.polyline.positions.getValue();
        for (var p = 0; p < positions.length; ++p) {
            terrainSamplePositions.push(Cesium.Cartographic.fromCartesian(positions[p]));
        }
    }

    // Asking for terrain heights is asynchronous, because the answer may
    // reside on the terrain server.
    Cesium.when(Cesium.sampleTerrain(viewer.terrainProvider, 14, terrainSamplePositions), function() {
        // Fudge the height values to keep off the ground.
        for (var k = 0; k < terrainSamplePositions.length; ++k) {
            terrainSamplePositions[k].height += 1.0;  // one meter off the ground
        }
        // Update all lines to sit on top of the terrain.
        var cartesians = viewer.scene.globe.ellipsoid.cartographicArrayToCartesianArray(
            terrainSamplePositions);
        var index = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j < entities1.length; j++) {
            var entity = entities1[j];
            var numPositions = entity.polyline.positions.getValue().length;
            var positions = [];
            for (var p = 0; p < numPositions; ++p) {
                positions.push(cartesians[index]);
                ++index;
            }
            entity.polyline.positions.setValue(positions);
        }
    });    

}).otherwise(function(error){
    //Display any errrors encountered while loading.
    window.alert(error);
});
```